# Is there a way I can record the rides I do on a Tacx Flow T1682 turbo?

Tags: turbo-trainer

I recently bought a T1682 turbo trainer second hand - the one with the orange and grey head unit, like in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGY2GAAzufs) It can display speed, distance and power, which is what drew me to it.

I'm curious to know if there is a way I can record the rides I do, using either Garmin Connect or Strava. I've done a lot of googling and I can't find a straight answer. The head unit has a data cable input which perhaps I could plug into a computer and use the Tacx desktop app, but I don't know the cable (it looks like a small ethernet lead). My Garmin Edge 520 also cannot see anything when I search for "Indoor Trainers" or "All Sensors" - Garmin's website ([here](https://support.garmin.com/en-GB/?faq=CHnxYj6F2OA6tN4QRRjEJ8)) leads me to believe it should work through bluetooth or ANT+.

Any advice on recording rides on this trainer would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had similar issues with a Tacx Satori not showing on Garmin head unit, you should however still be able to use it with apps like Zwift and from there you can sync data to strava and then to Garmin

Comment: I am looking for the same result. I have my speed and cadence coming from my Duotrap but missing the Power data from the Tacx turbo to have better training. Do you know if the Power data is accurate on this trainer?

Comment: There's not a lot of documentation on this model on the internet—it is no longer produced—but you pretty much need a "smart trainer" for what you want. This will have Bluetooth and/or ANT+ to interface with smartphones and/or bike computers, and will lack its own head unit. There's a smart version of this model in production now, but it's not the same. For now, I think you're stuck using spreadsheets and manual recording.

Comment: @AdamRice Thanks for your comment. I have a HRM and cadence sensor - if I use these with a Garmin speed sensor on the rear wheel, could I use my Edge head unit to record a ride that way?

Comment: I've never tried it, but I see no reason that wouldn't work. The only drawback (and this may be more of an abstract issue to you) is that modern training techniques are based on power output, and you have no way of capturing/regulating your power, which is what smart trainers do. I did see a post by a guy who hacked up an Arduino controller for the model you have, but that's quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Garmin's website (here) leads me to believe it should work through bluetooth or ANT+.

Garmin are referring to fully smart trainers, unfortunately the trainer you have is only semi smart.

Although your trainer will be able to send speed and power to apps like Zwift it is limited so power will not be that accurate, IIRC Zwift have non smart (or wheel on trainers) set at a limit of 3 to give a rough power guide.

Garmin 520 units will also only connect directly with a fully smart trainer.

Unfortunately you wont be able to directly link your trainer with your Garmin 520 but you do have some options.

Use a 3rd party app like Zwift, Rouvy, RGT, BKOOL (others do exist but these are the most popular) - You may find BKOOL the better option if you have saved routes you wanted to ride, you can upload them and ride them through the BKOOL app.

Any of the above apps have the ability to send recorded activities straight to Strava after you have finished the ride, if you have your Garmin Connect account linked to Strava you should see the finished ride available in both Strava and Garmin.

All the above is based on the fact you have access to a PC or Laptop, BKOOL and Zwift can be used with a smartphone or tablet.